# git helper script not being recognized

Tags: windows-7, git

In git-bash (on Windows 7) I've installed a git helper script in ~/bin/git-script but when I run it I receive the following:

```
$ git script
git: 'script' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Did you mean this?
    script
```

This is weird because it obviously has knowledge of the script command that I installed. Running it as `git-script` works fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This has been a year since it was asked, however, I suspect what was wrong was that the '~/bin' directory was not on the $PATH.

The fully-expanded path (such as /c/Users/Administrator/bin in the case of msysgit, rather than ~/bin), must be in the PATH in order for them to work like that.

Comment: I don't think it was directly because of $PATH because I can run it all by itself as `git-script` and that works fine.

Comment: @Bostonvaulter: Well, I had that happening in Mac OS X, the directory was in the $PATH, and I could run it fine explicitly, but not via 'git script', turns out that the '~' I had used was not getting expanded, I had to expand it explicitly...

Comment: oh, so you're saying that the ~ was being expanded by Bash but not by the git runner. That makes sense, I'll look into that.

Comment: @Bostonvaulter: Yep.